# How to keep multiple servers in sync file wise?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, rsync

I'm currently managing a cluster of PHP-FPM servers, all of which tend to get out of sync with each other. The application that I'm using on top of the app servers (Magento) allows for admins to modify various files on the system, but now that the site is in a clustered set up modifying a file only modifies it on a single instance (on one of the app servers) of the various machines in the cluster.

Is there an open-source application for Linux that may allow me to keep all of these servers in sync? I have no problem with creating a small VM instance that can listen for changes from machines to sync. In theory, the perfect application would have small clients that run on each machine to be synced, which would talk to the master server which would then decide how/what to sync from each machine.

I have already examined the possibilities of running a centralized file server, but unfortunately my app servers are spread out between EC2 and physical machines, which makes this unfeasible. As there are multiple app servers (some of which are dynamically created depending on the load of the site), simply setting up a rsync cron job is not efficient as the cron job would have to be modified on each machine to send files to every other machine in the cluster, and that would just be a whole bunch of unnecessary data transfers/ssh connections.

Comment: Use a git repository.

Comment: What about an NFS server?

Comment: For a git repository, I'm looking more for something that will immediately change the all of the linked systems once a change happens. -- As for an NFS server, as the machines are hosted on different subnets (and different regions of the country), the latency between them is too great.

Comment: NFS should work fine on different subnets, but the latency might be a problem. NFSv4 offers good NFS over TCP, which can help on WANs. However, I completely understand your concerns. We find that NFS over a high-quality WAN will still have problems, and NFS over the Internet would have even more issues.

Comment: How many servers are in your cluster?

Comment: The amount of servers I have in my cluster by default are 6 (the amount of servers that need the files), but this can scale exponentially depending on the load. I have an auto-setup script set up that automatically spawns new instances and rsync's files, but once the directories become out of sync it becomes a pain. To be honest, I've just been thinking about installing Dropbox on all of the machines and allowing Dropbox to sync the machines.

Comment: Rsync is great for syncing, but it's only a one way sync and doesn't work well with more then a handful of nodes. You may want to consider [DRBD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRBD) which can be used in clusters greater then two (called [Stacked Resources](http://www.drbd.org/users-guide/s-pacemaker-stacked-resources.html)). However, I am not directly familiar with DRBD is more then a two-node cluster.

Comment: @Michael Hampton can you please explain how a Git Repository would help in this situation?

Answer (score 5):

You may want to consider using Puppet or CFEngine to make changes to the servers.  Tools like these allow you make controlled changes to all servers.  They help a lot keeping the configuration of multiple servers in sync.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at GlusterFS. AFAIK it is available on EC2.

It's replication/mirroring is file-based, and it is quite easy to setup. Files reside in local directories on local filesystems of the nodes.

Specifically in your case you can setup mirror between all app servers and [safely access this local directory for reading](http://gluster.org/community/documentation/index.php/GlusterFS_Technical_FAQ#Can_I_directly_access_the_data_on_the_underlying_storage_volumes.3F) to work around FUSE overhead (but you have to write via glusterfs mount, so files are replicated on all nodes).

Comment: Isn't GlusterFS basically a networked file system? I'm afraid of using networked file systems because of the ridiculous throughput they put on the systems. Given this, I'm looking for something more like Dropbox, where only selective files get synced and each request does not have to load files over the network.

Comment: You might want to at least test out this solution.  It looks like the easiest and most reliable solution.  You can always stop using it if it eats up too much throughput.

Comment: GlusterFS is more about distributed than networked filesystem. For your case - i bet it worth trying. You can setup mirror on all your servers and it will sync files, not block devices.

Comment: Main drawback - it is FUSE filesystem, so performance penalty applies. But in your case, you can use the trick - access files on the nodes directly for read(no penalty), and write to them via glusterfs mountpoint.

Comment: @SergejAlikov welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for answering. Please expand your answer a bit and let us know how it could help answer the question. Please read the notification box above which says _We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution. Answers that don't explain anything will be deleted. See [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for more information._

Comment: GlusterFS seems to be a multi-node storage system, which I don't need. Are there any simpler file servers which would store the files it needs on each node offline so that only changed files are synced back to the master?

Comment: It is multi-node storage system which can be configured in different ways. My suggestion was to configure all nodes to have exact local replicas of the files, and gluster will take care of syncing _only_ changed files to all nodes, so the amount of sync traffic would be minimal possible.

This setup avoids centralized storage server, sync is file-based(like with dropbox) that is why it seems worth a try.

In your scenario I think the most complex part is to add new node to cluster when new server machine is spawned and delete it when server is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Being extremely familiar, I'm unaware of any Magneto installation that makes changes to files or directories through normal use other than

```
./var/cache   <-- should be on a distributed cache like Redis or Memcache
./var/report  <-- doesn't need to be network replicated
./var/log     <-- doesn't need to be network replicated
./var/locks   <-- the admin node should operate on a single server
./var/session <-- should be on a distributed cache like Redis or Memcache
./media/catalog/product/cache <-- doesn't need to be network replicated
```

In any case, a network file system like NFS wouldn't be a solid choice - unless you've got vast experience securing and tuning it over WAN.

Network block replication, eg. Gluster/DRBD would also not be a good choice. Performance is weak for Gluster (and complex to configure) and DRBD would have to use a multi-master filesystem like OCFS2 - not ideal.

Newer releases of Magento also support DB storage for media, for this exact reason - although this is beyond less than ideal and is merely Not A Good Idea.

Version control software (Git/SVN) would take care of your code-level requirements. You could easily add a hook to your staging machine to perform a touch-less multiple pull on the production systems. But wouldn't cater for admin uploads (images etc.).

It would make FAR more practical sense to merely redirect all your admin traffic and production roll-outs to a single node - then replicate from that source to your remaining nodes.

[Lipsync](https://github.com/philcryer/lipsync) is an application that would cater for your "Dropbox style" demands and perform changes and and when necessary. We've used it with Magento clusters on a number of occasions.

Comment: Looks like when you have full page cache enabled. you do need to sync `./media/catalog/product/cache` across all servers.